# Ionic Vertical scrolling inside Swiper JS not working on mobile

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I am trying to use a cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport inside swiperjs.
Everything seems te work fine on chrome desktop. But when I try it on a mobile or chrome desktop in mobile view, the horizontal slider can't scroll left and right.
Does anyone know how i can get a vertical scroll working inside swiperjs that also works good on a moble phone?

I created a example. Try switching to mobile view in the inspector tool, then swipe left/right

[https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/MarkNL2/stackblitz-starters-7qsbpn](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/MarkNL2/stackblitz-starters-7qsbpn)

Comment: i think you must have not wrapped the swiper component with a ion-page.